# Kubernetes - Configuring Angular to Work with a Backend API

Tags: python, angular, docker, kubernetes

I have two containers `Auth` and `Frontend`. I have managed to get both the containers working independently, I need to establish the link between the two to send and receive HTTP requests.

Generally, the connections are made in angular like `http://localhost:3000/auth/`.

**Note**: Both are in different deployments and services.

Should I be using Ingress or Nginx?

Comment: Just to clarify things: `Ingress` can be a `nginx`. Basically it's not the question about Ingress or nginx... maybe you mean should I use `Service` or `Ingress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Frontend` angular application, needs to connect to the `Auth` application an the two run on different networks, then just use the IP of your host running the `Auth` container. If your app requires load balancing, security or you just want to add another level of abstraction and control you may use a proxy like *Nginx*.

Answer (score 0):

service will do the job, you just need to replace localhost with service name.

Comment: If you browse the front-end app from outside the k8 cluster, you will not be able to browse the auth using the service name